# Why rowcount return -1 when row does exist?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I desesperatly try to check if a row exist with python in my mysql database.

I spent all my afternoon to try to find out!!!

I am impressed how such a useful function doesn't work properly after decades of existance! It is unbelievable. I guess expert will laugh about me :-). I am a newbie. So I aplogie for this simple question.

I've tried it all. I tried the "SELECT exist", I tried "to count the rows" and so many other stuff..... The countrows is the most common but it return -1 when I have existing rows in my database. I don't understand!

I tested from my pycharm and from phpmyadmin.

I attached screenshot.[image]

```
sql = "select * from websites where website = '" + item["website"] + "' limit 1"
self.curr.execute(sql, multi=True)
if self.curr.rowcount == 1:
    print("Website found")
```

Does anyone can tell me how can I check if a row exist or not in a mysql table?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please run `print(item["website"])` and tell us what the output is.  One possible explanation is that the record _is_ there, but the row count is greater than 1, so your if logic technically fails.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to run `self.cur.fetchall()` first before `self.curr.rowcount` is set..   But you can do it better with `self.curr.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) ...").fetchone()[0]`

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland but I get this error message: "mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from." It seems impossible to make a check with python :-(

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for trying to help me. The output of "print(item["website"]) " is the website: http://www.example.com/ which is in my mysql table. You can see on my screenshot that website is there. And I even print the sql request in order to test it directly in mysql. And it showed me result on mysql.

Comment: Are you certain that there is only one record with `example.com`?  Note that this URL does _not_ match the screenshot.

Comment: The url doesn't match the screenshot as I am not allowed here to publish links. But it match. There are several example.com in my table as my condition "if" didn't succeed, so the script added this url several times because the script thought example.com doesn't exist in table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally found the answer by testing hundreds of things. I had to remove the "multi=True". And I guess I had to add "self.cur.fetchall()" like suggested @Raymond Nijland

Here is the code which finally works:

```
    sql = "select * from websites where website = '" + item["website"] + "'"
    self.curr.execute(sql)
    self.curr.fetchall()
    if self.curr.rowcount == 1:
          print("Website found")
```

Thank you all for trying to help me.